# Apache CXF | JAX RS LoggingOutInterceptor - Access HttpServletRequest object

Tags: apache, web-services, logging, jax-rs, cxf

Folks,

I'm using Apache `CXF` (JAX-RS)'s `LoggingInInterceptor` and `LoggingOutInterceptor` to log the request and response objects to my web service and also to log the response time.
For this, I have extended both these classes and done relevant configuration in the appropriate XML files. Doing this, I was able to log the request and response object.
However, I also want to log the request URL in both these interceptors. I was able to get the `HttpServletRequest` object (Inside the `LoggingInInterceptor`) using the following:

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)message.get(AbstractHTTPDestination.HTTP_REQUEST);
```

Then, from the request object I was able to get the request URL (REST URL in my case). I was however, not able to get the request object in the `LoggingOutInterceptor` using this code (or by any other means).

Here is a summary of the issue:

I need to access the reqeuest URI inside the `LoggingOutInterceptor` (using `HttpServletRequest` object perhaps?).

Would appreciate any help on this.

Update: Adding the interceptor code.

```
public class StorefrontRestInboundInterceptor extends LoggingInInterceptor {

    /**
     * constructor.
     */
    public StorefrontRestInboundInterceptor() {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(final Message message) throws Fault {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) message.get(AbstractHTTPDestination.HTTP_REQUEST);
        if (isLoggingRequired()) {
            String requestUrl = (String) message.getExchange().get("requestUrl");
            Date requestTime = timeService.getCurrentTime();
            LOG.info("Performance Monitor started for session id:" + customerSession.getGuid());
            LOG.info(httpRequest.getRequestURI() + " Start time for SessionID " + customerSession.getGuid() + ": "
                + requestTime.toString());
        }
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = message.getContent(InputStream.class);
            CachedOutputStream outputStream = new CachedOutputStream();
            IOUtils.copy(inputStream, outputStream);
            outputStream.flush();
            message.setContent(InputStream.class, outputStream.getInputStream());
            LOG.info("Request object for " + httpRequest.getRequestURI() + " :" +  outputStream.getInputStream());
            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOG.info("Error occured reading the input stream for " + httpRequest.getRequestURI());
        }
    }


public class StorefrontRestOutboundInterceptor extends LoggingOutInterceptor {

    /**
     * logger implementation.
     */
    protected static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(StorefrontRestOutboundInterceptor.class);

    /**
     * constructor.
     */
    public StorefrontRestOutboundInterceptor() {
        super(Phase.PRE_STREAM);
    }

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(final Message message) throws Fault {
        if (isLoggingRequired()) {
            LOG.info(requestUrl + " End time for SessionID " + customerGuid + ": " + (timeService.getCurrentTime().getTime() - requestTime)
                    + " milliseconds taken.");
            LOG.info("Performance Monitor ends for session id:" + customerGuid);
        }
        OutputStream out = message.getContent(OutputStream.class);
        final CacheAndWriteOutputStream newOut = new CacheAndWriteOutputStream(out);
        message.setContent(OutputStream.class, newOut);
        newOut.registerCallback(new LoggingCallback(requestUrl));
    }

    public class LoggingCallback implements CachedOutputStreamCallback {

        private final String requestUrl;

        /**
         * 
         * @param requestUrl requestUrl.
         */
        public LoggingCallback(final String requestUrl) {
            this.requestUrl = requestUrl;
        }

        /**
         * @param cos CachedOutputStream.
         */
        public void onFlush(final CachedOutputStream cos) { //NOPMD

        }

        /**
         * @param cos CachedOutputStream.
         */
        public void onClose(final CachedOutputStream cos) {
            try {
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                cos.writeCacheTo(builder, limit);
                LOG.info("Request object for " + requestUrl + " :" + builder.toString());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOG.info("Error occured writing the response object for " + requestUrl);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you not able to get using `message.get(Message.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS);` or `message.get(Message.REQUEST_URI);` ? I think you should be.

Comment: @Garry Yes, I've tried these. Both of them resolve to null.

Answer (score 0):

Update:Since you are in Out chain you may need to get the In message from where you can get the request URI since the Request URI may null for out going response message.

You may try like this to get the Incoming message:

```
Message incoming = message.getExchange().getInMessage();
```

Then I think you should be able to get the Request URI using:

```
String requestURI = (String) incoming.get(Message.REQUEST_URI);
```

or

```
String endpointURI = (String) incoming.get(Message.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS);
```

If this is still not working, try to run the interceptor in PRE_STREAM phase like `Phase.PRE_STREAM` in your constructor.

You can also try to get the message from Interceptor Chain like this:

```
PhaseInterceptorChain chain = message.getInterceptorChain(); 
Message currentMessage = chain.getCurrentMessage();
HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) currentMessage.get("HTTP.REQUEST");
```

Comment: Adding Phase.PRE_STREAM in the constructor did not help. Also using PhaseInterceptorChain to get HttpSevletrequest yields a null result.

Comment: @va1b4av .. add your interceptor code to the question

Comment: Updated the original post.

Comment: @va1b4av .. Please check, I have updated the answer.

Comment: @va1b4av .. just curious to know...were you able to get through?